# Get custom post texonomy values

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to call texonomy value by texonomy name and post type like

```
$res=get_categories('taxonomy=category&type=course_type');
```

I am getting the result properly. but when I am passing the second custom texonomy name
it is giving me blank array. like my second texonomy is study and i am passing it like

```
$res=get_categories('taxonomy=study&type=course_type');
```

It is not working for study.

I have create the study texonomy by

```
register_taxonomy(  'study', 'course_type',  
array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'label' => 'Mode Of Study', 
    'query_var' => true, 
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'study'))
    );
```

this code and insert some study value but I am not able to get it on my page.
Can any one help me to get it.thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```html
$custom_terms = get_terms('study');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'course_type',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'study',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        
     }
}
```